# python equivalent to sed

Tags: python

Is there a way, without a double loop to accomplish what the following sed command does

Input:

```
Time
Banana
spinach
turkey
```

`sed -i "/Banana/ s/$/Toothpaste/" file`

Output:

```
Time
BananaToothpaste
spinach
turkey
```

What I have so far is a double list which would take a long time to go through both.

List a has a bunch of numbers
list b has a the same bunch of numbers but in a different order

For each entry in A i want to find the line in B with that same number and add value C to the end of it.

Hope this makes sense, even if my example doesn't.

I was doing the following in Bash and it was working however it was super slow...

```
for line in $(cat DATSRCLN.txt.utf8); do
        srch=$(echo $line | awk -F'^' '{print $1}');
        rep=$(echo $line | awk -F'^' '{print $2}');
        sed -i "/$(echo $srch)/ s/$/^$(echo $rep)/" tmp.1;
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your sed example is not equivalent to what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: So in bash I was doing this and it was working, but super slow...

Comment: you can actually run sed in python using the `subprocess` command.

Comment: Look into [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) and [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub), those are the rough Python equivalents to grep and sed.

Comment: Does the second file (tmp.1) only contain a search field from the first file on each line, or are there other contents as well?

Comment: Your sed code, your bash code, and your verbal description of what you are doing are three different things. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I would suggest replacing `for line in $(cat DATSRCLN.txt.utf8); do ... done` with `while read line; do ... done < DATSRCLN.txt.utf8`.

Answer (score 24):

Using `re.sub()`:

```
newstring = re.sub('(Banana)', r'\1Toothpaste', oldstring)
```

This catches one group (between first parentheses), and replaces it by ITSELF (the \number part) followed by a desired suffix. It is needed to use `r''` (raw string) so that the escape is correctly interpreted.

Answer (score 22):

A late comer to the race, here is my implementation for sed in Python:

```
import re
import shutil
from tempfile import mkstemp


def sed(pattern, replace, source, dest=None, count=0):
    """Reads a source file and writes the destination file.

    In each line, replaces pattern with replace.

    Args:
        pattern (str): pattern to match (can be re.pattern)
        replace (str): replacement str
        source  (str): input filename
        count (int): number of occurrences to replace
        dest (str):   destination filename, if not given, source will be over written.        
    """

    fin = open(source, 'r')
    num_replaced = count

    if dest:
        fout = open(dest, 'w')
    else:
        fd, name = mkstemp()
        fout = open(name, 'w')

    for line in fin:
        out = re.sub(pattern, replace, line)
        fout.write(out)

        if out != line:
            num_replaced += 1
        if count and num_replaced > count:
            break
    try:
        fout.writelines(fin.readlines())
    except Exception as E:
        raise E

    fin.close()
    fout.close()

    if not dest:
        shutil.move(name, source)
```

examples:

```
sed('foo', 'bar', "foo.txt")
```

will replace all 'foo' with 'bar' in foo.txt

```
sed('foo', 'bar', "foo.txt", "foo.updated.txt")
```

will replace all 'foo' with 'bar' in 'foo.txt' and save the result in "foo.updated.txt".

```
sed('foo', 'bar', "foo.txt", count=1)
```

will replace only the first occurrence of 'foo' with 'bar' and save the result in the original file 'foo.txt'

Comment: Windows sometimes crashes when doing the shutil.move, with this error: "WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process", so need to change open(name, 'w') to os.fdopen(fd, 'w') for the temp file

Comment: This function contains two bugs: (i) `num_replaced` should be initialized to `0` (not `count`), and (ii) it should break when `num_replaced >= count` (not strict inequality). The current implementation fails when called with a `count` greater than 1.

(I tried to edit this, but it got rejected because it 'deviated from the original intent of the post.')

Comment: Furthermore, it's more succinct to write `num_replaced += out != line`.

Comment: I'm also not sure what `try: XX; except Exception as E: raise E` accomplishes.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python3 the following module will help you:
https://github.com/mahmoudadel2/pysed

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mahmoudadel2/pysed/master/pysed.py
```

Place the module file into your Python3 modules path, then:

```
import pysed
pysed.replace(<Old string>, <Replacement String>, <Text File>)
pysed.rmlinematch(<Unwanted string>, <Text File>)
pysed.rmlinenumber(<Unwanted Line Number>, <Text File>)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can actually call sed from python.  Many ways to do this but I like to use the sh module.  (yum -y install python-sh)

The output of my example program is a follows.

```
[me@localhost sh]$ cat input 
Time
Banana
spinich
turkey
[me@localhost sh]$ python test_sh.py 
[me@localhost sh]$ cat input 
Time
Toothpaste
spinich
turkey
[me@localhost sh]$
```

Here is test_sh.py

```
import sh

sh.sed('-i', 's/Banana/Toothpaste/', 'input')
```

This will probably only work under LINUX.

Answer (score 3):

I found the [answer supplied by Oz123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843600/26510) to be great, but didn't seem to work 100%. I'm new to python, but modded it and wrapped it up to run in a bash script. This works on osx, using python 2.7.

```
# Replace 1 occurrence in file /tmp/1
$ search_replace "Banana" "BananaToothpaste" /tmp/1

# Replace 5 occurrences and save in /tmp/2
$ search_replace "Banana" "BananaToothpaste" /tmp/1 /tmp/2 5
```

#### search_replace

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
import shutil
from tempfile import mkstemp

total = len(sys.argv)-1
cmdargs = str(sys.argv)
if (total < 3):
    print ("Usage: SEARCH_FOR REPLACE_WITH IN_FILE {OUT_FILE} {COUNT}")
    print ("by default, the input file is replaced")
    print ("and the number of times to replace is 1")
    sys.exit(1)

# Parsing args one by one 
search_for = str(sys.argv[1])
replace_with = str(sys.argv[2])
file_name = str(sys.argv[3])
if (total < 4):
    file_name_dest=file_name
else:
    file_name_dest = str(sys.argv[4])
if (total < 5):
    count = 1
else:
    count = int(sys.argv[5])

def sed(pattern, replace, source, dest=None, count=0):
    """Reads a source file and writes the destination file.

    In each line, replaces pattern with replace.

    Args:
        pattern (str): pattern to match (can be re.pattern)
        replace (str): replacement str
        source  (str): input filename
        count (int): number of occurrences to replace
        dest (str):   destination filename, if not given, source will be over written.        
    """

    fin = open(source, 'r')
    num_replaced = 0

    fd, name = mkstemp()
    fout = open(name, 'w')

    for line in fin:
        if count and num_replaced < count:
            out = re.sub(pattern, replace, line)
            fout.write(out)
            if out != line:
                num_replaced += 1
        else:
            fout.write(line)

    fin.close()
    fout.close()

    if file_name == file_name_dest:
        shutil.move(name, file_name) 
    else:
        shutil.move(name, file_name_dest) 

sed(search_for, replace_with, file_name, file_name_dest, count)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this using tmp file with low system requirements and only one iteration without copying whole file into the memory:

```
#/usr/bin/python
import tempfile
import shutil
import os

newfile = tempfile.mkdtemp()
oldfile = 'stack.txt'

f = open(oldfile)
n = open(newfile,'w')

for i in f:
        if i.find('Banana') == -1:
                n.write(i)
                continue

        # Last row
        if i.find('\n') == -1:
                i += 'ToothPaste'
        else:
                i = i.rstrip('\n')
                i += 'ToothPaste\n'

        n.write(i) 

f.close()
n.close()

os.remove(oldfile)
shutil.move(newfile,oldfile)
```

Comment: "mkdtemp" creates directory. Use mkstemp instead.

Answer (score 1):

[massedit](https://github.com/elmotec/massedit)

you could use it as a command line tool:

```
# Will change all test*.py in subdirectories of tests.
massedit.py -e "re.sub('failIf', 'assertFalse', line)" -s tests test*.py
```

you also could use it as a library:

```
import massedit
filenames = ['massedit.py']
massedit.edit_files(filenames, ["re.sub('Jerome', 'J.', line)"])
```

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to Oz123 above, here is sed which is not line by line so your replacement can span newlines.  Larger files could be a problem.

```
import re
import shutil
from tempfile import mkstemp

def sed(pattern, replace, source, dest=None):
"""Reads a source file and writes the destination file.

Replaces pattern with replace globally through the file.
This is not line-by-line so the pattern can span newlines.

Args:
    pattern (str): pattern to match (can be re.pattern)
    replace (str): replacement str
    source  (str): input filename
    dest (str):   destination filename, if not given, source will be over written.
"""

if dest:
    fout = open(dest, 'w')
else:
    fd, name = mkstemp()
    fout = open(name, 'w')

with open(source, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

    p = re.compile(pattern)
    new_data = p.sub(replace, data)
    fout.write(new_data)

fout.close()

if not dest:
    shutil.move(name, source)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed or awk or grep in python (with some restrictions). Here is a very simple example. It changes banana to bananatoothpaste in the file. You can edit and use it. ( I tested it worked...note: if you are testing under windows you should install "sed" command and set the path first)

```
import os 
file="a.txt"
oldtext="Banana"
newtext=" BananaToothpaste"
os.system('sed -i "s/{}/{}/g" {}'.format(oldtext,newtext,file))
#print(f'sed -i "s/{oldtext}/{newtext}/g" {file}')
print('This command was applied:  sed -i "s/{}/{}/g" {}'.format(oldtext,newtext,file))
```

if you want to see results on the file directly apply: "type" for windows/ "cat" for linux:

```
####FOR WINDOWS:
os.popen("type " + file).read()
####FOR LINUX:
os.popen("cat " + file).read()
```